# What does Stack Overflow mean to you?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

What does Stack Overflow mean to you?

Is it simply a place to get questions and answers?

Is it is a community where you enjoy being around people like you?

Comment: It means there's a bug in my base-case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think Stack Overflow is a place where even the most beautiful prancing unicorn is no more important than the smallest [dust mite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_dust_mite). All shall have their chance at glory in the cage, but only one can be crowned Supreme Lord of the Rainbow Sphere!

Of course, I've been licking a lot of brightly-colored toads lately.

Answer (score 8):

It's a place where I can see a big number next to my name (and the badges don't hurt either).

I've lurked at programming sites before, but never participated. Then one day in September I saw a question on SO that looked easy, so I signed up and answered it. Then I got upvoted. Then I got a badge. Then I couldn't stop.

I also do quite a bit of editing, mainly because I like making things better; it drives me nuts when I'm on any other forum and I can't edit anyone's posts.

But for all that, I would likely have gotten bored and left months ago if it weren't for that number at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 8):

Mostly it's a place where I can find answers to my questions.  Partly it's a MMORPG.

Comment: Wherein the player roleplays someone who knows what the hell they're talking about.  Which is a wonderful break from RL.

Comment: @Kevin Montrose - have you ever considered consultancy?  You'd make a wonderful Dread Consultant Roberts ... ;-}

Comment: @Concerned: Stop it, you're scaring me!

Answer (score 8):

With Stack Overflow I can:

- Answer questions for fun - recreation
- Amuse myself while waiting for long winded batch jobs to finish - kill time
- Get a sense of helping somebody by ... helping somebody - participate in a community
- Get help with problems - better technical support than most vendors
- Pontificate on topics that interest me - can't be arsed setting up a blog
- Learn by digging around further to answer a question that I know part of the answer to - self improvement
- Learn stuff I didn't know by reading answers - self improvement
- Occasionally get pats on the back for stuff that people appreciate - warm fuzzies
- Occasionally get lots of upvotes for writing a good answer - sense of achievement

Answer (score 6):

I like Stack Overflow, because it gives the me the ability to contribute and promote growth. I typically try and facilitate this with my editing and moderating abilities. I have been around since the beta, and I have enjoyed watching Stack Overflow grow into an overwhelming success.

I like to think I played at least a small part in this.

Answer (score 6):

It's a steel, to keep me sharp. Not that my job doesn't challenge me day-to-day, but those challenges tend to be in the same areas; SO exposes me to problems and ideas that i wouldn't normally encounter.

Also, it lets me purge latent obsessive tendencies by fixing typos in other peoples' posts.

Answer (score 5):

I view it as a place to increase my skills and abilities in multiple ways. First of all, obviously, is technically. As a c# programmer there are many areas of the .NET framework I've never had to touch, but I've learned at least bits an pieces about many of those areas from SO. Additionally, I believe it has improved my communication skills. By trying to provide answers that get upvoted, I've had to learn to communicate my thoughts better. I believe this is immensely important to my day job because any time you work with a team, your ability to communicate and show people why you think what you do is extremely important. And finally, as my knowledge and answers have improved it has been a source encouragement and validation of my talents.

Answer (score 0):

I used to come for the [boat-programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19487#19487) questions, but they are banned. Now it leaves me mostly empty inside. I come to visit less and less.