# Answering your own question immediately

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving a personal technical blog to stackoverflow / serverfault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706)

If we find the answer for a difficult question, is it acceptable to post the question here and then answer it immediately?

If so, should we make one post for both the question and answer or make them two?

- [Stackoverflow: Should I answer my own question, or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not): My question focuses on answering a question immediately after asking it, rather than whether or not we should answer our own questions.

Comment: Yes, make          two.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not

Comment: Wrong question was marked as a dupe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to answer your own question. But you can mark it as accepted only after 15 hours are passed.
Good practice is to answer your own question in separate post.