# How to earn the Self Learner badge?

Tags: support, self-answer

We're [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq#119658) to answer our own posts, yet we [cannot answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-unofficial-faq#119591) our own questions.  [At the time this question was asked, that second link said "You cannot accept your own answer to a question." –G.]  How, then is the [Self-Learner](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner) badge awarded? The badge's page states:

> Answered your own question with at least 3 up votes.

So how does SO know that I answered the question. Or does it simply accept any response from the author?  Further, are reputation points awarded to the original author, or the most recent author of the post?

Answer (score 15):

I think it means that you posted an answer to your own question (not marked your own question as answered). If you post a question and then post a response and someone up-votes it 3 times then you earn the badge.

Answer (score 14):

Ahh, thanks guys...Of course I didn't find [this related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not) until I had posted it :)

Comment: lol, this answer got me the 'Self-Learner' badge. +1 Funny, anyone?

Comment: actually that is pretty funny, lol

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to accept your reply.

You just have to reply to your own question and also receive 3 up votes on that reply.

Answer (score 3):

You simply post an answer to your own question, then wait for 3 people to up-vote it.

Note - you can 'answer' your own question, you just can't 'accept' your own answer.

Comment: Now we 'can' accept our own answers, I have done it several times. It just doesn't provide the 2 points. Of course you wrote that in 2008, things must have changed since.