# Putting [SOLVED] in the title of a question

Tags: discussion, title

So I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846315/solved-controlling-visibility-of-html-controls-using-databinding) question recently, and then figured out what was wrong myself after an hour or so of investigation.  Nobody else had put the correct solution down, so being a thoughtful chap I posted my answer and put an update in the question.  Being that there wwere no other upvoted answer and that I'm not able to mark my question as accepted for a couple of days I decided that I'd also put [SOLVED] in the title to show to anyone looking through the list of unanswered questions that its been solved.

Now clearly I've broken some sort of unwritten rule here, because someone has downvoted it - apparently because of the [SOLVED] in the question.

Never mind that the question is well written, correctly tagged, and that its even a pretty reasonable question - none of that is worthy of an upvote, but trying to be helpful and putting [SOLVED] in the title is worth of a downvote...

The best bit is that whoever downvoted the question was quite probably perfectly capable of editing the title themselves anyway, but they chose to downvote it instead...

Gah! (`</rant>`)

Anyway - so I take it there is a taboo against putting [SOLVED] in the title of a question?

Comment: I'd consider voting you down for closing your rant without having first opening the tag ...

Comment: Should we edit posts to removed the [solved] ?

Comment: @MartinBeckett I generally do nowadays

Comment: @Justin then I will as well - a democracy of two!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several threads that show you how to deal with that situation give you reasons why to answer your own question. Look here:

- [stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not)
- [is-it-poor-etiquette-to-answer-your-own-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/is-it-poor-etiquette-to-answer-your-own-question)
- [Moving a personal technical blog to stackoverflow / serverfault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706)

So even deliberately asking a question to answer it yourself is encouraged, as well as, after a waiting period of 2 days, accepting your own answer. These sites are all about great answers to great questions. Who cares whether both come from one person.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the correct way is to add an answer and accept it (even if you yourself provide it)

Comment: I see you already posted it as an answer and got an upvote

Answer (score 4):

Mark your own answer as accepted to signal the question is solved.

If people downvote you for the wrong reasons, complain on meta, and many people will vote you up if you're right.  (I did here.)

Answer (score -1):

"Users with less than 100 reputation points cannot answer their own questions for 7-8 hours," may be the error message that causes people to do this.  Consider reducing the points required to release this restriction?

Comment: This is a separate [feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=feature-request), although the 8 hour limit has a [good rationale](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93749/allowing-users-to-answer-their-own-questions/93766#93766), so it's probably staying around

Comment: @Michael: Did you mean for the feature request link to go to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93749/162705)?

Comment: @Chris No, I meant it like "This should be posted as a feature-request instead of an answer". I don't think it's a duplicate, that question was proposing some sort of draft answer system; this is just "it should require less rep/time to self-answer"

Comment: @Michael: Great, thanks for clarifying!