# Reject edits that consist of adding the word "solved" in the title

Tags: feature-request, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommend better procedure for self-answering when editing question title with “SOLVED”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86278/recommend-better-procedure-for-self-answering-when-editing-question-title-with-s)

When someone edits their question, and they add the word "solved" in the title, it indicates that they are editing to add the solution to their question.  This results in downvotes, [meta discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/putting-solved-in-the-title-of-a-question), mod flags, further edits and comments left to inform the user of the proper way to handle this, and other types of fanny pain.

Instead, I'd suggest using the post quality testing tools to sniff out when "solved" is added to an edit, then inform the user that,

> If you are editing this question to add a solution, please understand that this is not allowed.  Please cancel your edit and add the solution *as an answer to your own question*.  After the required waiting period, you can [mark your answer as correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235).

Comment: Sounds good.  Maybe check for "solved" at just the beginning or end of the title?

Comment: doesnt this get linked to this question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86278/recommend-better-procedure-for-self-answering-when-editing-question-title-with-s

Comment: Could I get around this by saying [sorted] instead of [solved]?

Comment: @Neal: Crap, that question has a shnitty title.  Gonna edit it.

Comment: @Wont im sorry lol

Comment: @Wont -- you even commented on that question back in April haha

Comment: @Neal: Not only that, I *downvoted it.*  Dunno what the hell was wrong with me.