# Is there any reason to ever have an answer duplicated in a question?

Tags: discussion, answers

Quite a while ago, I suggested an edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052691/trouble-with-qxtglobalshortcut), to remove "[SOLVED]" from the title, and remove

> **EDIT:** The answer was {x}

from the body. When [trashgod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/230513/trashgod) reviewed my edit, (s)he approved it, but then put the "EDIT: answer was x" part back in.

It was my understanding that answers were not to be put in the question, they go... in the answers. But I wasn't about to try to override someone with 30k rep, when I'm sub-400.

Comment: Interestingly, the same answer was already posted by the asker *as an answer*.

Comment: Yeah, the asker originally put all the info in the question, before being told to put it as an answer. But then they left the answer in the question as well!

Comment: [I wish that original edit was never allowed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98679/reject-edits-that-consist-of-adding-the-word-solved-in-the-title)  Nothing worse than "SOLVED" in a question title.  Skeeves me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, no. Maybe in some obscure edge-case combination of reasons - *maybe* it would make sense - but in the example given it looks like a simple "question" => "answer".

Burninated.