# Is it OK to add [Solved] to the title of a question?

Tags: discussion, edits, title

I was confused when I saw this Question with [Solved] in its title where I couldn't find a solution: [My Propertgrid Repeats on every controls click present on to the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518091/my-propertgrid-repeats-on-every-controls-click-present-on-to-the-form-solved).

Then I found out that the "[Solved]" part was put there by someone else through editing like these:

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8518091/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8513706/revisions

I was feeling that this was not how it's supposed to be done and searched meta to find, that it is indeed discouraged to do so:

- [Reject edits that consist of adding the word "solved" in the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98679/reject-edits-that-consist-of-adding-the-word-solved-in-the-title)
- [Putting [SOLVED] in the title of a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/putting-solved-in-the-title-of-a-question)

But on the other hand, the user who did the edits has a whole lot of reputation so I might me missing something here. So what's the correct thing to do? Should those edits be reverted?

Comment: High rep != great editor every time.

Comment: Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519597/read-data-from-a-com-port-using-tcp-solved

Comment: Sigh, just trying to avoid other SO contributors waste time on a resolved question like I did when I discovered the "I solved it!" comment from the OP.  Okay, okay, not appreciated, I'll stop it.

Comment: Even if the OP got his problem solved there's no time wasted in providing a good answer for someone else having the same problem since they will definitely miss the "I solved it" buried somewhere in the comments.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You're right, putting "[SOLVED]" in the title is not the right thing to do.

If the OP made the edit then leave a comment explaining the correct behaviour - i.e. post the solution as an answer.

If someone else made the edit then roll back the edit and leave a comment addressed at the editor explaining the right thing to do.

In either case if the solution hasn't been posted as a separate answer after (say) 24 hours then there's nothing to stop you posting it yourself. You might want to make the answer Community Wiki so there can be no accusations of "stealing" other people's reputation.

In this case it's a 200K+ user who made the edit - they should know better. I've rolled back the edit.

Comment: Thanks clearing this up for me :)

Comment: I find it extremely strange and disturbing that it was 200k+ user doing that...and that [he's doing it regularly](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant?tab=activity&sort=revisions)!

Comment: @Bobby - as do we all. We are investigating.

Comment: Just noting that such edits are _highly_ uncharacteristic of said 200k user, and we're currently looking into it.

Answer (score 38):

No, adding "[SOLVED]", or any variation thereof, to a question title is *forbidden* (if it isn't strictly, through any documented consensus, then it should be ...and punishable by, ...something dire.)

There is absolutely no need to do this anyway, it treads on the system: it's almost like adding some form of custom tag, which isn't quite a tag, just mess; whether an answer has been accepted or not is the decider - whether the OP went off and solved it elsewhere, by themselves, is irrelevant.

Comment: This is a fine answer. I think we can mark this question `[SOLVED]` now!

Comment: @TheP.G.RepMiningCo.: You beat me to it by 20 seconds...

Comment: The tile of this question already contains "[Solved]" ;-)

Comment: The SO robots already warn you as you are typing a question if they think it is "subjective, and likely to be closed".  Why can't they do the same sort of thing if they detect somebody adding the string `solved` to a question title? (I have a question that I asked, and subsequently self-solved in 2011.  I noticed that somebody has just (yesterday) removed my `[solved]`)