# What is the policy for typos or silly syntax error questions?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Say, there is a question titled "Mysql query doesn't work", and a query inside, assembled from randomly picked operators.

What is the policy for such questions?

I mean *real* policy, not imaginary one.

- What to do with all the dozens of answers it gets in seconds?
- Should it be closed?
- If so - what is the point in closing a question that already has a dozen answers, one of them accepted?
- How to advertise your point of view on such a questions among thousands of occasional passers-by?

A real working solutions please.
Not how it is intended to be in the perfect world, but how it might work on the real site of Thousands Silly Typo Questions And Eager Typo Spotters?
Please, no contradictory answers too. "It should be closed *but* why not to be nice and help a neighbour" means no policy at all.

A solution that can cover at least 10% of such questions would be a great step in cleaning the site and deserves a bounty which I promise to put up.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123741/should-questions-where-a-problem-arose-from-a-typo-be-closed - close as too localized.

Comment: Why are you adding 'solved' to the title? That's not allowed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question

Comment: Also, this is a community edited site - if there are problems with your content we *will* fix them. None of the edits done were harmful in any way, shape or form, so why are you complaining?

Answer (score 8):

> What to do with all the dozens of answers it gets in seconds?

Nothing. These people should ideally be flagging and close voting, but this isn't an ideal world.

> Should it be closed?

Close it as too localized.

> If so - what is the point in closing a question that already has a dozen answers, one of them accepted?

Preventing more answers. While the acceptance tick discourages folks from answering, it doesn't discourage completely. I've had my fair share of answer-after-accept answers, some of which got accepted later.

Also, it removes [broken windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory).

> How to advertise your point of view on such a questions among thousands of occasional passers-by?

Comment. Vote to close. Post in the relevant chatroom asking for closevotes. With any luck, you'll attract like-minded people.

Answer (score 2):

If the question can be solved by pointing out the silly typo or syntax error, and that typo is unlikely to occur to others (the question is not going to be helpful others), you *vote to close* as Too Localized. Simple as that.

You can then, optionally, list the question in the [Typo Close-to-vote request chat room](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions). It'll be added to a backlog and may well be deleted as well.