# What should I do with a question that was due to a careless error on my part?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840609/spring-security-filtering-by-ip-only-no-authentication), and it turns out that the problem was due to my own carelessness (kind of like discovering a typo in my code, but not exactly as silly of a mistake).

What should I do with my question in this case?  Should I close it, delete it, or answer it and leave it alone?

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked before (although not about this specific question), but my search-fu is failing me.

Comment: @AlEverett I too was trying to search for a similar question but wasn't sure what to search for!

Comment: [What is the policy for typos or silly syntax error questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176485) is close, but it really shouldn't be closed as a duplicate of the question it's closed as a duplicate of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's unlikely to help anyone in the future, delete it.

If it's possible that someone else might do the exact same thing, leave it.

Comment: ...but if you _do_ leave it, make sure it has an accepted answer tha describes precisely what solved the problem, even if you have to write the answer yourself.

Comment: And if you write the answer, write it as an actual answer, don't just edit the solution into the question,

Comment: ...and try not to make it a habit. If you have a lot of deleted questions you might find yourself question-banned. But just one shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You can't delete your own question if it has answers. (I've tried before!) Should we flag for deletion in that case?

Comment: @MarkAmery You can delete it as long as none of the answers have an upvote.