# Question Title Appended with "Closed"

Tags: discussion, edits, vote-to-close

If a user changes/edits the title of their article to `CLOSE`, `CLOSED`, or `RESOLVED`, etc., could there be a message instructing the user to instead answer, close (if they'd have that option), or delete the question?

I was on this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313840/php-sql-php-not-process-login-closed, and the OP just changed the title which leaves the question still open/unanswered. I've seen this in the past a few times as well.

Comment: Related: [Is it OK to add "Solved" to the title of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this suggestion makes sense, but most of the times such questions are immediately closed by the mods or the community.

Also, as this is a very rare event. So, probably it is best left to the community for taking a call on closing it