# What should be done when a new user fixes their own code?

Tags: discussion, edits

Consider the following situation:

- A user asks a question
- Someone leaves a comment below the question saying there's a typo in the code
- The OP sees the comment and edits the question to correct the typo, thus making the question invalid
- The OP comments below saying that the problem was resolved successfully

These are the options I see:

- Rollback the edit
- Close the question for not demonstrating a minimal understanding of the problem being solved
- Downvote the question and move on to the next
- Flag it for moderator attention saying it should be deleted

If we let the question remain, people may answer it, but OP already got their issue resolved -- and from a community point of view, the question doesn't really add much value. So what should be done in such cases?

Note: I've already seen [Editing questions to fix incorrect code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141749/editing-questions-to-fix-incorrect-code) but that doesn't really address this issue. If there is a different question that I missed, please let me know in the comments

Comment: This was one of the reasons the old "Too Localized" close reason existed.  I'd say Vote to Close with either minimal understanding or a custom reason that explains why.

Comment: Vote to close the question; Off-topic -> other -> simple typo, not helpful to future visitors.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions

Comment: @Habib newer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192846/191174

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typo questions are rarely useful for future visitors.

Vote to close the question; pick either:

- Off-Topic -> Other -> and fill in "because it is a simple typo, and this question is not helpful to future visitors".

or use

- Off-Topic -> "Minimal understanding"

if the code was entirely missing but you managed to debug purely from the textual description or error message (go psychic debugging!).

Comment: You'll generally want to prefer 'other' in these cases, 'minimal' understanding is meant more for _write this for me_ or _look at this giant wall of code and tell me why it doesn't work_ sort of questions. That said, I kind of miss the 'no longer relevant' option we used to have way back when.

Comment: @TimPost: Indeed; qualified it it a little.