# What to do when someone other than the author changes a question to fix a substantive problem with the code

Tags: discussion, edits

See https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20426753/revisions. Someone other than the OP changed the code to address a substantial problem with the it that was addressed as part of my answer. The problem was admittedly peripheral to the core question, but it was a primary differentiator between my answer and another answer submitted at the same time.

Any suggestions on what to do in this situation? Leave it be? Edit it back? Something else?

Update: I just found [Editing questions to fix incorrect code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141749/editing-questions-to-fix-incorrect-code?rq=1), from the "Related Links" section on the right, which is pretty relevant. I have to keep remembering to check there rather than just searching for answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

People should not be editing code in questions that are not their own. Such edits should certainly not get approved in a review! In this situation, I would roll-back the edit.

If I really wanted my wannabe-moderator badge, I'd possibly see who approved the edit and check they are generally paying attention in their reviews (notifying a moderator if not).

Comment: In fact, one of the reviewers does appear to have a bit of a problem and I've notified a moderator.

Answer (score 4):

An unfortunate consequence of the reputation rules on these sites is that inexperienced users are incentivised to make edits. **Two repulation points is too tempting.**

I'd suggest you roll back an change that invalidates the answers and, if this is typical behaviour for a user, flag said user for moderator attention.

Comment: I would argue it's the robo-reviewers that are the real problem. This edit should have been rejected.

Comment: @Duncan: I agree; the buck stops with them. But in defence, the answers aren't particularly visible in the edit approval page. Perhaps also  the reviewer reputation limit is too low?

Comment: @Bathsheba Raising the reputation requirement won't help unfortunately, too often high rep users approve bad edits. [In this case](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3523491) one of the approvers has 13k rep.

Comment: @Bathsheba They don't need to see the answers to know that it's an inappropriate edit.  Editing the code in a *question* to fix a problem with it is almost never a good edit.  The *only* exception would be if the question author said, in comments, that it was a typo when posting the SO question, and that his real code doesn't have that mistake.  Any other time a problem with the question's code should be addressed through comments or an answer, never through editing the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call folks motivated to *fix code* a problem on a programming Q&A website, much less attribute such motivations to the reputation gained from doing so. The problem here is that the editor should've posted an answer instead; perhaps he thought the change was irrelevant to the question, or perhaps he simply doesn't quite understand the purpose of editing.

Comment: @Shog9 Would you say the same thing for the reviewers who approved the edit, particularly the 13k rep approver with ~600 review approvals?

Comment: Nope; I would suggest it's likely they didn't know what they were looking at. @Peter.

Comment: @Shog9 Can you clarify? Are you saying it's likely they didn't realize they were looking at a substantive change to code in a question?

Comment: That would be my guess, @Peter. Really not possible to know for certain without asking them.

Comment: @Shog9 Last followup: What would be the appropriate mechanism/context to ask one of them? A comment @ them under the question itself? Would they be notified of the comment? Is that too "meta" for SO?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no good way to contact reviewers unless they happen to be in chat, @Peter.

Answer (score 3):

If you see an edit that "breaks" a post (for whatever definition of "break" you're comfortable with), roll it back **and let the editor know that the edit wasn't appropriate.**

How?

Simple - leave a comment.

> Hey @user2422869, thanks for trying to improve the question, but please be careful when editing such that you don't inadvertently fix the problem being asked about! If you can identify the problem facing the asker, post an answer instead - that way, the question + answer have a chance of helping someone else making the same mistake in the future. – Shog9♦

It's amazing how effective communication can be.