# Inline title editing

Tags: feature-request, edits, 10k-tools, title

Just like SO provide users with 10k+ privileges to edit tags inline

[image: image sauce]

Can a similar `edit-title` be provided? This will be a real help with currently ongoing [Community Edit Request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172501/212576)

Comment: You shouldn't be editing _only_ the title; though I agree that sometimes it's all that's required.

Comment: This would be nice, that's for sure.

Answer (score 3):

I do agree with Ben. On most of the post where the title has to be modified there are also other issues. It's pretty rare that only the title is bad.

Especially with post with *[solved]* or whatever else in it. Whether :

- They need "too localized" flag / any other close flag
- Or they have the answer within the question body
- Or they have some pretty bad formatting
- Or they have a lot grammar mistake.
- Or they lacks proper capitalization
- Or they lacks proper tags
- Or they have noise in the post *(thanks/signature/please help)*

With all the revisions I made on posts like that, I have yet to found one that was perfect as it was and only needed to have the word *[solved]* removed.

There's always something to improve. And by just editing the title, it does not help the community that much because it "frees" plenty of posts with issues in the wild west!

Comment: I always eat my hot dogs with hot dog buns, but i'm glad you can buy them separately. Just because you often edit title and body together, I don't think providing a title-only-edit for 10k+ users will result in people simply not editing the body.

Comment: The circumstance I find really annoying is when I go to edit the question, or the title, and find that the OP has gamed the 'this word is not allowed in the title' rules by misspelling it, so you have to put the effort into rewording their misspelled title to pass the filters.  I know it's a known problem with its own set of questions; it just bugs the living daylights out of me.  Indeed, unless I've done an incredible amount of editing, I sometimes (often) just give in and discard my edits because I can't be bothered to spend time working out how to retitle the question.

Comment: @Jonathan though it won't be solved by inline title edit. But I do agree that this is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

YES YES YES!

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > [image: CAGE AGREES!]

Comment: Won't you are abusing the quote system way too much today haha!

Comment: @HugoDozois Would flagging this for mod attention help? :)

Comment: @devnull Wont was a mod before so no! :-p

Comment: @HugoDozois Given that he took the liberty to post __this__ *answer*, it was kind of obvious.

Comment: @HugoDozois: [Apparently, people think this is fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197517/nested-quote-trolling). I'm happy to oblige.  Of course, I'm happy to drink at the local watering hole up until the time they chuck me out.