# Nested quote trolling

Tags: discussion, blockquote, trolling

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > Should this be allowed?

Comment: How is this `different` from *other* meaningless **mis-uses** of `formatting`? It will *just* be `edited out` **anyway**!

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Okay, then I'll just do it everywhere, as it will just be edited out anyway.

Comment: /me is tempted to edit it out of the question ...

Comment: I'm curious as to which form of widespread problem this is: A current one, or one that becomes widespread now that it's in the open.

Comment: @Won't Intentional abuse of formatting despite warnings already has a mechanism; moderator intervention.  This would be no different.  Someone using this mechanism in good faith wouldn't have a problem, someone trying to just be mean probably has much more harmful formatting changes that they could make.

Comment: @Servy: It's all true.  However, it's also easy to special case out of existence.  So, if there is no legit reason to allow this kind of formatting (e.g., like how `\s[2,]` is collapsed into `\s\s`), and its use results in people wasting time editing it out, then why allow it in the first place?

Comment: I feel compelled to point out that your example [looks like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U4lv7.png) on mobile Safari.

Comment: @TimStone: comment flagged for ASCII boobie

Comment: @TimStone Wow! That's even more coolish than what it looks like here!

Comment: Yes, this should be allowed. It's beautiful.

Comment: @Won't Sigh, was going to close this post as 'pointless', then saw that you posted it.

Comment: I don't see any point in writing code for this until someone points out an actual instance of this in the wild.

Comment: Also, "trolling"? Has the meaning of that word really diluted this far? :|

Comment: @Blorgbeard: You don't think using this inappropriately, forcing others to edit your posts, can't be used to troll people?  BRB, going to >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>answer some of your questions

Comment: @Won't no, I think it *could* be used to *annoy* people, but I have never seen it happen. Have you?

Comment: Only if it has a haiku in the middle

Comment: @Blorgbeard: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197517/nested-quote-trolling?noredirect=1#comment625203_197519

Comment: @Blorgbeard [maybe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188305/about-tags-cart-shopping-and-shopping-cart/201999#201999)

Comment: @ColeJohnson you would think if Won't wanted this to be disallowed, he wouldn't do it himself..

Comment: @Blorgbeard: The consensus is that it's okey dokey.  So game on.

Comment: No, the consensus is that it's not worth writing code to disallow. Lots of annoying behaviour isn't explicitly coded for, but still frowned upon. For example, using [this](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Standard&t=i%20troll%20u%20lololol) to post all your answers is not forbidden! So go nuts!

Answer (score 40):

That becomes unreadable in the mobile version (screenshot for iOS 6, iPhone 5):

[image]

Comment: Dude! That's NSFW!

Comment: @Bart: Like that's the *first* time ever that mobile devices at work are used for NSFW purposes...

Comment: Wow... a vanishing point?

Answer (score 25):

There is plenty of other format abuse

Like any form of format abuse, it should just be edited out.

Like so...

[image]

Comment: @Won't Case in point

Comment: `Like any form of format abuse`... except for lots of whitespace.  Whitespace is collapsed.  So there is precedent for preventing forms of format abuse.

Comment: Isn't whitespace-collapsing already part of the markdown-spec? If so, then it would not really be a precedent. Personally I don't believe in modifying what the users posts, unless there is a *clear* and *visible* trend of some formatting always being abused. And personally I've never seen this used.

Comment: Part of the SE ethos is to not waste user's time.  That's why, while you can edit to improve, users who get their stuff downvoted or put on hold for low quality tend to get blocked after enough time wasting has happened.  There really isn't a mechanism for tracking users who constantly abuse formatting, therefore wasting the time of those who edit to fix.  No mechanism, other than people running into the same guy more than once and flagging.

Comment: @JoachimSauer One thing I see constantly abused is code formatting for emphasis, or merely because something is a proper name, or just totally random.

Answer (score 19):

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > ## yes sure why not
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > it's not really that bad or worth making rules or special formatting logic to deal with

And if it is that bad we have an entire community of caretakers who can handle it.

(Where's the "trolling" part come into it anyway?)

Answer (score 16):

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > This space intentionally left blank.

This could probably be cleaned up automatically by converting multiple leading `>>>>>` symbols to a single `>`.  Is there ever any reason to have more than one?

---

As Servy notes in the comments, sometimes it is necessary to quote a passage that contains a block quote, so we should allow for two leading `>>` symbols.  Of course, that opens up the possibility that someone might want to quote your quote containing a block quote. Then that person would need three `>>>`.  This slippery slope can only lead to our hero, Won't, waking up on a beach in Ken Watanabe's dreamscape.  Maybe we *should* just edit out abuses of nested quotes when we see them?

Comment: "Is there ever any reason to have more than one?" If you're ever quoting something that has a block quote in it.

Comment: @Servy Maybe limit it to two `>>` then?  Also, would you lead with a block quote?  I think I need to see an example of this in the wild.

Comment: I could imagine someone quoting an Eric Lippert post, and he opens with quotes quite a lot.  It would probably be pretty contrived, to have more than two though, that I agree.

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  You can't have more than two space characters in a row in any non-code text; it gets collapsed into two spaces.                                                                                   << 50+ spaces, where did they go?

Comment: @BilltheLizard What if you wish to quote a quote which is quoted inside a block-quote?

Comment: [The source of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18895616/1)

Comment: The bigger issue is that imposing a limit requires the parser to know how many quotes deep it is, which may be easier said than done. I think balpha's take on this is still "just don't do that", but I won't claim to speak for him.

Comment: The spaces are still there, @Won't, the browser just collapses them in accordance with HTML rendering requirements. The system does take the liberty of ignoring some whitespace in comments for validation purposes, but it doesn't ever actually remove it. Incidentally, [this can cause some issues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105461/link-in-comment-not-displayed-correctly-when-automatically-moved-to-chat).

Comment: @TimStone: Hmmm.... Hadn't thought about that.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to automatically forbid this? Seriously?

Comment: @KonradRudolph "Maybe we should just edit out abuses of nested quotes when we see them?"

Comment: Perhaps it was actually misformatted code. For example about a merge conflict. In that case such a replacer would make things worse.

Answer (score 13):

## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## <sub>What about this? Is this also trolling? :-)</sub>

Comment: ...and it's even edit-proof!

Comment: Move it a bit to the left, to overlay the downvote button ;-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd not completely edit proof, you just have to be determined to edit it.  But very cool.

Comment: @Arjan lol, that's probably possible!!

Comment: @psubsee2003 sure, I had to edit such post on formatting sandbox to be able to edit my own post, hence this "skill". :-)

Comment: I can see how you did it. It's a nice idea. On a side note, the checkbox in my answer hider renders above the text and is clickable

Comment: EPIC.  Makes it hard to edit/flag any answer.  Huzzah.  Now, if this was exploited by spammers, it would *have* to be addressed.

Comment: You call getting your picture underneath the posting [nothing visible](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/208765/revisions), @gnat?

Comment: @Won't well, I'm sure someone can come with a shortcut. My own way: first, find the post ID. Using dev tools it's easy to get the ID from the vote arrows: http://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Xcb.png (hint: this very post ID is 208765) now with this at hand it's matter of feeding it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tsFhT/1/embedded/result/) into the textbox and clicking Go. You'll end up straight in [the edit page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/208765/edit). I'm almost sure someone can even come with a userscript to make it even easier. :)

Comment: No need for dev tools, just upvote and then get the answer id from the link in your voting history ;-) By the way, as usual, the mobile theme makes hacks like this [look funny](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kGNjb.png). (On a serious note: [the Printliminator](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ThePrintliminator/) is also useful to get rid of blocking elements...)

Comment: @Arjan yeah, have to use `<h1>` to keep the text from just shrinking so it makes it HUGE on mobile!

Comment: If anyone got a problem with this answer please downvote or even flag, don't try [to edit and remove the formatting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22472). Thanks. (it's not a test, it's to prove a point)

Comment: -1 I can downvote this.

Comment: @ColeJohnson sure, I know you can edit but it requires extra effort. As for downvote... plz b kind 2me ser! :)

Comment: Aw, the move to meta.se (to different css) invalidated this answer :(

Answer (score 8):

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > ### #
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > Maybe
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > ## #
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > #

Answer (score 8):

Does this happen *that* often? If not, regular users like you or me can just fix it.

Like so:
[image: See, somebody fixed it.]

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't even render in the mobile app.

[image: It doesn't show up in the mobile app.]

I'm not sure why one needs that deep of quote nesting.  It seems reasonable that this gets addressed.  But, where would that leave all of the other formatting abuses?

Comment: The same place they always were. No sense in addressing it. We can Zalgo things, nbsp them into the middle of a blockquote, force line breaks… not much of a difference.

Comment: Ugh. This is boring. I like [@bfavaretto's version](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197530/220538) better :P

Answer (score 3):

This is a significant problem for mobile users<sup>1</sup>. A large number<sup>2</sup> of nested blockquotes in an answer will lead to an unresponsive page, *eventually* leading to an error message:

> This page has become unresponsive

This effects other tabs even after the offending tab is closed. As such this isn't just an irritating format bug but may lead to a page going effectively offline for mobile users

<sup>1</sup> tested on Galaxy s3 running android 4.1.2

<sup>2</sup> a large number is about 2 and half complete lines:

`>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>`

Or in evidence [here, mobile users beware!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210745/220332)

Comment: It also leads to *504 Gateway Time-out* errors on the revision history of a post. Possibly (this needs to be confirmed) the Suggested Edits review queue is affected in the same way.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this is so brutal to render, indenting doesn't seem that cpu intensive

Comment: Of all the ways to break a browser, you must admit this one is pretty creative! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd By joining forces with yours (which I would use the share link to but... you-know) the whole of stack overflow could be brought down for mobile users