# Warning when play with blockquote

Tags: discussion, support, bug

When I type ">" (blockquotes) more than 3 rows, it throws some warning message and with some special effects that exceeds the sidebar.

> [image]

[image]

Posted as answer, but I got 2 answers instead of one and I don't know how it happened.

[image]

Comment: Solution: Stop playing with blockquotes.

Comment: https://skitch-img.s3.amazonaws.com/20111023-rnc9uu656rtdwwd8g3c1r2sbc5.png

Comment: @Mysticial made my day!!!

Comment: Why in heck would you *need* 94 x 2 = **188** nested blockquotes?

Comment: @michaelb958'saSleigh I waited for new question arrival :)

Comment: Your computer is too weak for formatting you are trying to use :P

Comment: Most computers would be weak when you force them to process 188 nested blockquotes in javascript ;)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131825/191174

Comment: @Yannis see BLOCKQUOTE OVERFLOW , some of them played before me http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/131825#131825

Comment: Would I be correct in saying this is formatting person A can put on an answer that will lead to the page crashing on person B's computer?  If so why aren't people taking this seriously

Comment: @RichardTingle Depends if the issue is also there when reading an answer. I start to get warnings when using 3 full lines of blockquotes, but when submitting it I get a *504 Gateway Time-out* after 2m30s, so I can't test that.

Comment: @Stijn I'm running somne tests not, submitting from computer seems impossible, trying now from mobile

Comment: @Stijn when submitting, I got 1 answer posted and it also shows the answer in editor and then I refreshed it submitted the second answer with same post.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197517/nested-quote-trolling

Comment: Testing this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210749/220332) it seems that assuming these get posted sucessfully they don't then cause problems

Comment: [This actually causes problems for mobile users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210785/220332); browsing this page on mobile locks up my browser even after this tab is closed

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you just shouldn't use that many block quotes, BUT you are right it couldn't hurt to add a maximum in the system of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I just wonder if the editor is SE-native? If it is using external library, forking it to add this limit might hurt. I admit I don't know technical details, I just think "couldn't hurt" may be too brave statement ;)

Comment: @Mołot https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/

Answer (score 2):

Abuse of styling should always be edited out. There is no point in trying to block all ways of abusing styling.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like my answer did get posted in the sandbox: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210743/167646

Reading the answer causes no issue, but trying to edit it (3 lines of blockquotes) causes the warning message for me. Loading the revisions page of a post takes a very long time to load or even time-out.

<strike>I think the risk is rather low, if this happens in a suggested edit it'll be rejected and</strike> I doubt a 2k+ user would want to risk his/her account just to do this. Perhaps a compromised account could cause an issue. It wouldn't hurt to add a limit to the nesting I suppose, 10 sounds like a good number.

*Update*
If the revisions page has an issue, there could also be an issue when reviewing suggested edits. That means this issue could be more troublesome than first thought.