# The [code-coverage] tag could use a little cleanup -- too many questions asking for tool recommendations

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, off-topic, clean-up

There are currently over [400 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcode-coverage%5D+is%3Aquestion+tool) on Stack Overflow for the [code-coverage](/questions/tagged/code-coverage) tag that refer to tools in some fashion.

It appears that a large chunk of these questions are simply asking for tool recommendations, and are still open, and should be closed and/or deleted, such as:

[Code coverage tools in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518362/code-coverage-tools-in-java)

[Code Coverage tools for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348850/code-coverage-tools-for-php)

[Code coverage tools for regexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645012/code-coverage-tools-for-regexes)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022513/code-coverage-tool-for-jquery-code

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904571/code-coverage-tools-in-java

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666455/structural-coverage-of-java-code/

I'm out of close votes for the day already, so have fun!

Comment: F7U12: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%5Bsolved%5D

Comment: I'm really not sure how to take that comment, so.... thanks for closing the example questions I guess?

Comment: Your example questions reminded me of another recurring issue we have: People putting `[Solved]` after titles. Makes me crazy.

Comment: @George Stocker - Gotcha, thanks!  I'll add those to my To Do list as well...

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172501/community-edit-request-solved-fixed-answered