# Posting self-discovered solutions on SO

Tags: discussion, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it poor etiquette to answer your own question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/is-it-poor-etiquette-to-answer-your-own-question)

Should SO members be encouraged to create new topics and post *solutions* to problems they have spent quite some time figuring out a good solution for, if they have not found a close answer or even a related question on SO for those problems?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/is-it-poor-etiquette-to-answer-your-own-question and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they should.  That is one of the explicitly allowed use cases for the site.