# Modifying your own question because you have a better solution?

Tags: support, edits, questions

Curious as to what the protocol is here for when you want to answer your own question.

Say for example I post a question with code illustrating the question. I later on come up with a solution. Now, even with the "improved" code, it could be better.

Is it taboo to answer your own question?

Or is it better to add the "second version" of the code to the original question?
Append, prepend?

Or should I delete the original question, and post a new one with the code I came up with?

Other thoughts?

Comment: Answering your own question isnt taboo.. I think there is even a badge for it (i.e. Self-Learner)

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/is-it-poor-etiquette-to-answer-your-own-question