# What if my question has no answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)
>   [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer)

I had asked a question on SO sometime back -

[Is there a Eclipse plugin for Spring JDBCTemplate code generation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007260/is-there-a-eclipse-plugin-for-spring-jdbctemplate-code-generation)

Along with that I was researching solutions for the problem. Now i definitely know that there is no so such plugin and hence no "correct" answer to the question.

What do i do with it? Leave it open?

Comment: at the time he asked the question he didn't know the answer.

Comment: @Lukman: The answer is the same...okay, alternately: [Should I not answer my own questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions).

Comment: Classic hangup at SO.  *No is a valid answer*.  It just doesn't get any helpful votes so nobody answers it.

Answer (score 9):

Add an answer, ideally showing how you now "definitely know" there are no such plugins.

After the appropriate limit (which I can't remember now) you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you can post an answer stating that you are convinced there is no answer for that question and you have given up. Then accept that as an answer (don't worry you won't gain reputation for accepting your own answer). And also add a note saying that you are still looking for somebody to come and post an actual answer later.

Answer (score 4):

If you offer a big enough bounty, someone might even write it for you if it does not exist :).

Answer (score 3):

I would answer your own question saying it's not possible, then mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just because there is no such plugin now doesn't mean there can't ever be.

Leave it open.

In fact, [I recently just answered one of my own **old, open** questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896758/can-someone-rid-me-of-these-turbulent-t4-template-editors/6152369#6152369) when, ironically, I saw a new T4 template editor plugin was released for VS.