# Can I answer my own question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)
>   [Should I not answer my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions)

I have posted a question, and then later I found the mistake and solution by myself. Can I give this as the answer to my own question? If I give that answer, what will happen?

Comment: belongs on meta.stackoverflow but yes you can

Comment: @Bobby this is totally not a duplicate of that question.This guy finds a solution after asking.

Comment: @JohnnyCageWins: Yes, it totally is a duplicate. The same rules apply. Why *wouldn't* they?

Comment: @Cody there is a big difference between `already knowing the answer and asking a question to share what you know` and `asking a question without any answers while you keep looking for an answer by yourself, too`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, but should consider several things first:

1. If somebody else found the mistake and tried to solve it, you better let them Edit their answer with the correct fix then accept the answer.
2. If there are answers already but none is relevant, then by all means, add your own answer with what you did to fix the problem and accept it.
3. If there are no answers and the question is "local", meaning not something generic that can be useful for others, then just delete your question after putting comment notifying others you found the mistake, so that it won't get undeleted.

Edit:
Looks like the [question in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689046/gridview-binding-problem) falls into the 3<sup>rd</sup> category - you can click the "delete" link and as it has no answers, there will be no harm done.

Comment: Yes, this should be the accepted answer. It's very important to note that not all questions are created equal. If yours is based on a stupid mistake and is unlikely to help anyone else in the future of the Internet, you should just silently delete it. (Sorry, I'm all out of upvotes, though.)

Comment: @Cody the question at hand here is not likely to help anyone else, thus I believe it falls to the third category and better be deleted. By the way, good find of the real duplicate.

Comment: Right, I was agreeing with you. :-)

Comment: @Cody I gave half an upvote for ya

Comment: This is a helpful answer, thanks! I suggest using "them" instead of "him" to refer to a generic Stack Overflow user, though :)

Comment: @Keara sure thing, this answer was written almost 10 years ago, I was totally oblivious to those things back then. Feel free to edit such things yourself in the future, the post author and/or high rep users of the site will see your edit suggestion and likely approve it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, just click the mark that says this is the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. You can also accept it.

Depending on your reputation, you might have to wait a bit before you can do either of those, but it's perfectly acceptable, and welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can accept your own answer, and if it is the correct solution this is even wanted: other can easily see the solution to the question at a glance (especially important if there are already wrong/incomplete answers that might even have a higher vote than your answer and thus will be shown before your answer; lots of readers would miss your answer if you didn't mark it as such).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to answer your own question and accept it as your solution.It is actually a great thing to answer your own question, when your question didn't get enough views or answers or you couldn't get a solution from SO, because that question will have a solution below it and other people will benefit from it.You have to wait for some time to accept your answer to your own question like 2 or 3 hours or days, you will see it when you click the tick.

I have done it a couple times.

[could not translate expression into sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755873/could-not-translate-expression-into-sql)

[Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936301/local-sequence-cannot-be-used-in-linq-to-sql-implementations-of-query-operators-e/5937278#5937278)