# A question I answered has vanished

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

A Question I answered on SO has vanished, it was about how to get drive information in Delphi, to be honest I earned a lot of rep from that answer so it must have been popular.

The link to the answer that doesn't exist anymore is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644242/get-drive-information-free-space-etc-for-drives-on-windows-and-populate-a-mem/1644261#1644261

Today I told a colleague to go and search for it as they wanted to do something similar and bang they could not find the question.

Could someone tell me where it has gone, please?

Comment: It's been deleted.

Comment: @ChrisF I can see its been deleted, I just wonder why?

Comment: If you want to recover the contents, search in Google using keyword `cache:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644242`. Repost it in a blog or something if you want.

Comment: @Matt: that's not the deleted question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635573/delphi-enumerate-the-disks-and-other-drives-on-windows-pc I'd however edit that answer accordingly so that it contains the full extract instead of just a link.

Comment: @Chiciray Thanks for that, I have the code it just supprised me that the question had been removed, I am unclear as to what rule if any it was in breech of.

Comment: @Chichiray: good point :P :$

Comment: The question was terrible and fully deserved to be deleted. However, your answer was good and deserves to exist. So there's an obvious conflict. My suggestion is to post a new, well-asked question, and then answer it yourself with the same answer you already posted. As others have pointed out, the content is available in the Google cache, and answering your own question is strongly encouraged around here.

Comment: Thanks Everyone. I am not sure about asking and answering my own question, that just feels a little like fraud to me. Cheers for all your help.

Comment: It's not fraud at all. Related: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to), [Should I not answer my own questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions), [Posting and answering questions you have already found the answer to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/), and many more. I think it's a fine idea here.

Comment: There's a dupe question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635573/delphi-enumerate-the-disks-and-other-drives-on-windows-pc You may want to repost the answer from [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1644242&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) in there and ask a mod (or community) to reopen the question as the dupe has now been deleted.

Comment: Since you had already posted an answer on the dupe linking to your original answer, I took the liberty of inlining your answer there. Should save you the trouble of recovering it from the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was deleted on August 17 by Tim Post (a moderator).  It appears that the question and its answers were quite contentious, and the questioner had some attitude; I assume that's why the question was deleted (plus it had many many downvotes).

Comment: The question was not great, but the answers were good, the Questioner certainly had an attitude problem.