# Why people ask questions when they already know answer?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, self-answer

I have seen many questions by users on 'SO' who post question without providing code and/or less description and then right after posting question post answer. What is the reason of the asking question and posting answer him/herself right after posting question?? The only reason what I think is users who do this just want to show their knowledge. But I think if people want to share their knowledge then they should better write blogs and/or tutorial instead of posting questions and answers on SO.

I think a user should not given authority to post answer to his/her own question for like 30 mins to few hours after posting his/her question. Probably, other users could also give better answers because everyone thinks differently.

Comment: If you already know the answer and are posting the answer to help others its bad faith to pretend you don't know the answer. If someone else has a **better** answer then they'll post it, otherwise they're just wasting their time

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ for the position on self answering

Comment: Many people when comes to a solution they don't think for improving that or thinking for improved one.. I'm just saying not letting users to answer their own question for some time..

Comment: Users can't accept their own answer for 2 days after posting the question already. I know that's not what you're asking for but does that cover your request?

Comment: @SalmanZaidi How does pretending not to know the answer improve the quality of the question/answer pair? If anything being able to start from the OP's answer can only make answers better and reduce duplication of effort

Comment: thanks for the blog link.. I do know that it's encouraging to post question and answer.. I just wanted to make my point clear about not posting answer right after posting question..

Comment: Some people may be posting question that they already know to provide a searchable piece of information.

Comment: Nb as this is your first meta question; be aware that downvotes on meta often mean "we disagree with your idea" rather than "this is a bad question"

Comment: @SalmanZaidi I gave you an upvote, the society I live in frowns upon people doing that kind of thing (I understand we are in a global environment and SO encourages it).. Here, someone who does that is considered "up themselves" or "on themselves" or to "have tickets on themselves" no wonder my country has made no major technological innovations... hmmm ;)

Comment: @RichardTingle I upvote if the person has put effort even if I don't agree, if they are new,to encourage  (well potentially encourage bad questions).. naw I usually post a comment explaining my vote, hey se what they did to my insightful question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189503/metas-unicorns?noredirect=1#comment585310_189503 ;)

Comment: @Yve I too would be in favour of a [change in the system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/the-meaning-of-down-votes-in-meta-vs-stackoverflow/182028#182028) but the system is sadly as it is for the time being

Comment: @RichardTingle good link.. how can I give u my email>

Comment: @Yve Do I have email; yes. Do I look at that email at all regularly; no. Is that incredibly inconvenient for everyone who works with me; also yes

Comment: @RichardTingle that's funny, I alwasy have my phone with me (albeit on silent) and my email open when I'm online

Comment: The reason people ask questions that they already know the answer to is simple, sometimes you will learn more about something that you already know by asking someone what they know no one can know everything about one subject because just as our world changes so do the subjects that we have come to know do.If you want to ask me any questions contact me at my personal gmail account (ryverrogers14@gmail.com)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What is the reason of the asking question and posting answer him/herself right after posting question??

To help others who might have the same question.

> The only reason what I think is users who do this just want to show their knowledge. But I think if people want to share their knowledge then they should better write blogs and/or tutorial instead of posting questions and answers on SO.

Why can't they do both? Why can't they post these things on Stack Overflow? What's wrong with that?

And don't answer that until you've read that [our official policy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) is strongly in favor of this. There are [lots of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) [Meta questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions) about it, too.

> I think a user should not given authority to post answer to his/her own question for like 30 mins to few hours after posting his/her question. Probably, other users could also give better answers because everyone thinks differently.

Why would the delay be useful? Other people can still submit answers if they have something else to contribute or a better way of doing it. That's one of the advantages of posting on Stack Overflow in the first place, rather than your private blog or website. Having an answer does not "close" the question, even if that answer is accepted by the asker.

Answer (score 6):

[It is absolutely okay and encouraged to answer your own question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). We even have a checkbox on the "ask question" page that opens a second editor so you can submit the answer right alongside with the question. If you have solved a problem that other people might have as well (of course, the question still has to be on topic for Stack Overflow, and both the question and the answers should be good), why should you have to wait for someone else to post the question to share your solution?

And it's not preventing anyone from posting a second or third answer saying "here's another (maybe even better) way to solve it." And if you hadn't posted your self-answered question in the first place, maybe those other, better answers would never exist.