# Why could it be considered gaming the system if you answer your own question?

Tags: discussion, gaming-the-system

Why could it be considered rep whoring to ask a question that you already know the answer to and then answer it yourself?  Doing this adds to the value of the "knowledge base", and may help others when the question appears in web searches.  And if the question and/or answer are good enough to get upvotes, why shouldn't the same person get points for both?

(The source of this question is [John Millikin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3560/john-millikin)'s comment on this StackOverflow question: [How do I mock an open used in a with statement (using the Mock framework in Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289894/).)

Comment: It would actually be considered 'rep whoring'

Comment: Other duplicates http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/moving-a-personal-technical-blog-to-stackoverflow-serverfault/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/should-i-ask-questions-i-already-know-the-answer-too-and-answer-them-myself/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is acceptable.

It's not required, but good SO etiquette is to also mark the *answer* (not question) as community wiki to avoid the appearance of begging rep.  This way others can still earn rep in the normal way if they post something to the question, and if someone wants to reward your time they can still do so by voting on the question.

Comment: Community wiki is no longer available.

Answer (score 5):

It is acceptable and encouraged to answer your own question on the StackOverflow sites.

See this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not).

Comment: I've never considered it rep whoring.

Comment: I actually agree.