# Asking where you may already know or have an answer, even a guess

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, self-answer

What should I do when I think I have an answer to my question, but to me feels at best a guess?

For example, in the question body I might include the guess as part of the background or assumption,

> [...] I think that the answer to this question is blah blah blah. Please prove me wrong.

If I'm wrong I've added an explicitly erroneous solution that other answers can skip, helping them clearly see what is right and what is wrong and understand the bigger picture.

On the other hand if my guess is correct there might be answers like "I think you answered your question", or answers adding just a tiny bit to my own guess.

In such cases, what answer should I accept when none of the answers fully answer the question and the correct answer is my initial guess?

I could refrain from posting my own guess and let people try to answer the question. But then am not saving others time by answering (well, actually guessing an answer) my question? The time that could be better spent on something else.

Is it a good strategy at all to post my guess as to what the answer is in the question body, or should I refrain from it?

I could also probably post my guess as an answer along with my question right away. But that'll be just a guess, not an actual answer. How appropriate would that be? I wouldn't have asked if I had surely known the correct answer in the first place.

Comment: Basically you want to ask a question that's reaffirming or refuting what you already know

Comment: I don't necessary *already* know it. But based on my previous experience or my own research (that didn't produce the exact answer) I can guess as to what the answer could be.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/should-i-ask-questions-i-already-know-the-answer-to-and-answer-them-myself http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46849/can-i-ask-a-technically-solved-question-for-better-advice http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225780/what-is-the-best-way-to-ask-a-question-when-i-believe-i-already-know-the-answer

Comment: Gosh, @random you edited my question upside down. Are you a professional editor or what? :D