# Can I post a question with an answer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, self-answer

Sometimes I will face a problem and either figure out the answer myself, or find the answer on a site other than StackOverflow, but I think it might be helpful to other people.  Is it acceptable (or is there a different method) for posting the problem and answer?

If I had a blog, I'd throw it on there, but I don't.

Comment: We really need a better titled question to point at for the appropriateness of asking a question and answering it yourself afterwards...

Comment: How about http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513 or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/ or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/ ?

Comment: @Gra: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32311/do-not-delete-duplicates

Comment: Given there's a [FAQ question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to) in there, these should all be closed as dupes of that question.

Comment: There's even a badge (Self-Learner) for this if your answer gets enough upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many ways, that's *exactly* what StackOverflow is for.  If you have a programming question which hasn't been asked, and doesn't have an obvious solution (and based on what kinds of questions get asked, it seems *no* question has an obvious solution for everybody), you should ask it.

Conversely, if there's a question asked and you have a good answer for it, you should post the answer so others can share your enlightenment.  It's uncommon that you'll post the question and the answer at the same time (usually you'll ask the question, do some research, find a solution, then come back and post an answer) but there's nothing wrong with it.

As an added bonus, occasionally someone else will post a better solution than the one you found.  That's a win-win.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the question is in the question and the answer is in the answer.