# Can I answer my own question?

Tags: discussion, answers, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should I not answer my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions)
>   [Should I ask questions I already know the answer to and answer them myself?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/should-i-ask-questions-i-already-know-the-answer-to-and-answer-them-myself)
>   [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)

This is related to my question [Detect Autoscrollposition Value Change In Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768576/detect-autoscrollposition-value-change-in-panel).

Can I answer this question myself? This is an effort to share knowledge.

Comment: From context, I think [Should I ask questions I already know the answer to, and answer them myself?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/should-i-ask-questions-i-already-know-the-answer-to-and-answer-them-myself) is a closer dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can answer you own question, and usually even accept it after 2 days
(at least on SO and SF)

Comment: means i have to answer after two days?

Comment: little information require. If i have to answer my own question than what i have to do. I mean the way of edit my original question or shall i click to answer your question.

Comment: @mahesh - click to answer your question. You can do that now. You'll have to wait two days to accept it. Please also read the answers here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Comment: yes you can answer it now. You may *accept* it in two days.