# Can I post how-tos (questions with provided answer) to stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, support, posting, guidelines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I answer my own question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65363/can-i-answer-my-own-question)

Sometimes It happens to me that:

- I have a question/problem or I'd like to know how to do something in the proper way;
- I don't find the answer in stackoverflow or I just find poorly related questions;
- I **don't** ask the question  in stackoverflow because I'm pretty sure I'm near to find the answer alone;
- After spending many hours of googling/studying the problem I eventually find the proper solution to my problem.

At that point I'd like that question to be in stackoverflow with the answer I found. Not because of my vanity or stackoverflow score but because I spent many hours struggling and I'm sure others had or will have the same problem in the future. Can I use stackoverflow with this purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: The dupe just links to three other posts. Here are the two relevant ones: [Should I ask questions I already know the answer to and answer them myself?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/should-i-ask-questions-i-already-know-the-answer-to-and-answer-them-myself) and [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)