# Posting Answers instead of Questions

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, posting

While Q&A sites are certainly a good place to find answers to one's problems, I think it would be better to collect solutions. During my daily work I quite often solve a specific problem. Wouldn't it be nice if I could store the solution somewhere so that others can find it (including myself if I have the same problem later and forget how I solved it)? Kind of a Code Snippet Repository.

I think the quality of the solutions would be much better this way. You could also formulate questions and attach them to the solution (= answer), so it would look and behave like a Q&A site. The process of posting a solution would have to be very easy, of course. Nobody wants to spend too much time after solving a problem. I imagine that there has to be a tight integration with the OS or IDE, maybe directly allow posting of marked code with a shortcut.

What do you think?

Comment: So you're proposing to NOT post questions and answers like we're used to? If you *do* want to use the existing system, then: duplicate of [Should I ask questions I already know the answer to and answer them myself?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/should-i-ask-questions-i-already-know-the-answer-to), [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know), [Moving a personal technical blog to Stack Overflow/Server Fault](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/moving-a-personal-technical-blog), ...

Comment: as meanwhile you've been back here: care to explain if you're proposing *new* functionality?

Comment: I think my question was of the same kind as the ones of the other threads you posted above. I will read them and let you know whether it is so or not.

Comment: Well, after reading the other threads I think it's okay to post a question and an answer at the same time. Although I'm not sur how the community will react. But I'll try and see. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can post a question and answer it yourself.

But it would be polite to wait at least a day before accepting the answer to allow others to provide an even better answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure this waiting period is even enforced. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Ralph, correct, 48 hours.

Comment: Well, for the use described in the post, this waiting period is an absolute showstopper. I will never wait 48 hours after I solved the problem until I post the answer. Furthermore, I don't want pepole to try to solve my problem by answering the question, because it's already solved.

Comment: @rayml: Nothing's stopping you from *posting* the answer. The waiting period is before *accepting* your own answer. Big difference.

Comment: @raymi - if you are not interested in seeing the contributions of the community in those 48 hours (which may improve upon your solution), then I would suggest that SO isn't the site for you.

Comment: I'm glad the waiting period is enforced. @raymi, at SO we like to have the best answer for each question. So its great that you can answer your own question (there is a badge for that) but others need to have the chance to answer to keep things fair.

Comment: I have no problem with others answering my question or improving my solution. After all, it's not my goal to earn points or badges, it's about providing solutions to problems. I simply didn't realize that the waiting period is for accepting the answer (I thought it's the period until I can post the answer).

Comment: @raymi - that's fine; glad that's cleared up. I guess I got confused when you said *I don't want people to try to solve my problem by answering the question, because it's already solved*, but I understand that you were thinking you couldn't even post your answer in the meantime.