# What to do when you answer your own question while writing it?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, asking-questions, behavior

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

It just happened that my question didn't exist anymore (I found the answer) while writing it:

[git website update strategy - how to sync dev and live repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112852/my-git-website-update-strategy)

But I found the content so valuable that I posted it anyway.

Surely, it will add value to stackoverflow and other trying to resolve the same problem.

But, sadly, there was no question in the "question" anymore.

What should I have done? I don't have another proper place to publish that content...

Comment: Possible Duplicates: [Moving a personal technical blog to Stack Overflow/Server Fault](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/moving-a-personal-technical-blog-to-stack-overflow-server-fault) [Should I not answer my own questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions) [Should I ask questions I already know the answer to and answer them myself?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/should-i-ask-questions-i-already-know-the-answer-to-and-answer-them-myself)

Comment: As the FAQ says: *It’s also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you’re on Jeopardy! – phrase it in the form of a question.*

Comment: Another possible duplicate: [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)

Answer (score 3):

Write the question as a question, and answer it with an answer.

Don't put the answer in the body of the question.