# I want to share a minor discovery with the community, how should I?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I ask questions I already know the answer to and answer them myself?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2800/should-i-ask-questions-i-already-know-the-answer-to-and-answer-them-myself)
>   [Should I not answer my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions)

I think I just discovered a small feature in [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29)  that I hadn't heard about before, that I think is pretty useful. I have read a good amount of blogs on using Eclipse efficiently, but I never came across this thing. Now I want to let other people know/give back to community since I benefit a lot from random things posted online.

What is the best way to go about this? I know I could keep a blog, but getting people to follow and read it would be a lot of work, especially since I don't discover much :) The obvious answer in my mind was to ask a question on Stack Overflow and answer it myself. Is that ever a good option? Any other suggestions?

Comment: [As long as you phrase it as a question and answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) yes.

Comment: Now I am curious about your discovery ... let me know about it when you post it please.

Answer (score 8):

Setting up your own blog and posting it there is a good way to so, or emailing a renown blogger asking him to blog about it may be an alternative.

What you are suggesting is absolutely fine (ask a question and answer it), though one has to wonder about how many eyeballs it will end up getting.

Answer (score 7):

This is a good example of why [there should be a Stack Overflow Community Blog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110998/139837). Many of the other SE sites have [their own blogs](http://blogoverflow.com/) for this sort of thing; why shouldn't SO?