# Pseudo reversed concept for stackoverflow site

Tags: discussion, answers, community

Hi all!

I'm wondering if following would work as a community site:

Instead of posting a question user posts a quick tip for how to achieve certain actions in certain conditions. For example:

- keyboard shortcuts (for power user);
- code snippets (for stackoverflow);
- anything other (for any other site of the family);

Additionally one would post advantages and disadvanteges of proposed actions. After all - there is more than one way to do it in any situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this on the SO family of sites as long as you phrase it in the form of a question, then provide your tip as an answer.  Then the community can fill in the "more than one way to do it" for you.

Comment: true, but IMHO answering own question with the tip just doesn't sound right .)

Comment: @Eimantas: Then your HO is wrong: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706 :)

Comment: Eimantas: It's perfectly legitimate to answer your own question, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq - "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question."

Comment: Thanks, Eric! I guess i was searching using the wrong terms for this issue ,)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't is the same simply removing the question mark at the end of the question?

Comment: Like a question mark makes a difference. I'm Ron Burgandy?

Comment: true again, but main concept is "ask a question" and not "give us a tip" ,)