# Why with "encyclopedic" style posts is "Accept own Answer" timer existant?

Tags: feature-request, support, accepted-answer, self-answer

This comes from Ask ubuntu, but this is the examples of this being a hindrance:

[How are Ubuntu bugs' importance values decided?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153692/how-are-ubuntu-bugs-importance-values-decided)
[How do Bugs get Categorized and what is the lifecycle of a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153765/how-do-bugs-get-categorized-and-what-is-the-lifecycle-of-a-bug)

Even though I ticked the checkmark that said "Would you like to answer your own question" (see [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)), I'm stuck in the pit where I can't accept that answer which is direct documentation-supported until the 2-day accept timer expires.

Could this feature be changed such that when you do this and it has, say, greater than two upvotes, you can accept your own answer (if and only if you did a Q&A knowledge-sharing-style post)?

Comment: I wouldn't think you'd be impacted by this restriction at all.  You know...because of your user name.  `</terribleJoke>`

Comment: @jadarnel27 +1 on your comment, even though its a terrible joke

Comment: @LordofTime I like jokes now. Jokes are **cool**.

Comment: I don't think there's any other reasoning than the ones given in, for example, [Why must I wait 2 days before accepting my own answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6044/why-must-i-wait-2-days-before-accepting), [48 hour accept own answer delay wastes other answerer's time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134269/48-hour-accept-own-answer-delay-wastes-other-answerers-time) or [Reduce accepting-own-answer delay](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97425/reduce-accepting-own-answer-delay). The fact that you can answer your own question *right away* doesn't matter, I feel.

Comment: Related: [Now that I can answer my own question before I even ask it, how about reminding me to accept my own answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133092) (and linked from that post: [Will there continue to be 48-hour accept timer for self answered questions?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4692))

Comment: If your answer is the "right" or "best" one, it should still be in two days. Maybe you'll get some upvotes in that period to validate that.

Comment: [*points at the +10 on the one overnight*](http://askubuntu.com/a/153693/10616)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Answering your own question, and then accepting it immediately, basically sends the message that "This is the right answer, and I don't wish to see any more answers."

That's not how the site works.  Even if you could accept your own answer right away, it doesn't prevent others from posting answers, and preemptively accepting an answer as correct essentially short-circuits the crowd-sourced vetting and collaborative answering that takes place on any posted question, because many people won't bother to participate if the question already has an accepted answer.

I've seen too many people try this and then get substantial feedback from other users that their premise is flawed, or their answer has some factual difficulties.  This is valuable feedback.

Accepting an answer right away effectively puts too much ownership of the question into the original poster's hands, and potentially opens the door for all sorts of abuses, like companies using self-answered questions as proxy blog posts, which obtain a degree of immunity from closing/deletion because the number of initial views is reduced, due to an answer being accepted.