# When should I post a question on Stack Overflow, and why am I getting negative feedback?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes, asking-questions

Sometimes I ask a question which is not that "super-duper" for so many people, but actually before posting I really struggled hard to get the answer and because of that if in the end I myself post the answer, then some of the SO users give the negative feedback because the answer was not too great.

So due to pressure I had to delete these kind of questions.

But I never felt right because of getting negative feedback.

But if I don't post my question then it takes a long time to get it.

So what am I supposed to do—post the question and let the world do what they want or should I struggle hard to find the solution on my own?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, are you asking about answering your own questions, or asking questions in general?

Comment: abt some of my own questions

Comment: Can you show some examples? Maybe people here can help with constructive suggestions on what to do differently. Very often, small changes in the wording can make all the difference.

Comment: Is there any possible way to show us a question you're talking about? Or were they all removed? It might help us understand and advice you.

Comment: actually I have asked questions like these only twice and both the time this happened and i had to delete the questions... sorry 4 that....

Comment: Just to get this clear am I right in saying the following: You asked a question for which you did not get an answer. You managed to solve/self-answer it and were subsequently downvoted because your solution might not have been the best?

Comment: you can see the peer pressure badge....

Comment: @Bart: almost same ..... actually sometime I asked a question of something, which actually comes from in between of the development of projects.... which generally I guess everybody won't be understanding it...but the problem may have arised due to some other issue which upon self try I finds out but till then downvoted...

Comment: Don't take downvotes personally. Learn from them, take them as an indication that there is something you could/should improve. Which you seem to be doing anyway by asking your question here. So good for you. But never let them pressure you into doing something you don't want to do.

Comment: yes I will try my best for that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have a programming question that meets the guidelines in our [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq/), then **you should ask it!**

Negative feedback from experienced users can be very helpful, because it can suggest ways to improve your question and/or answer. All posts can be edited at any time to add additional information, and we very much encourage people to do so.

However, you should not feel "pressured" by anyone to delete your posts. Just because someone downvotes a question or answer does not mean that it should be deleted. It simply means that they think the post is not helpful. If something *really* needs to be deleted, a moderator will step in to do that. For questions specifically, those that don't belong are *closed* by the community—downvotes do not necessarily imply that something "does not belong". Downvotes are just the way that the community ranks content in terms of helpfulness or usefulness.

If you're talking specifically about asking and answering your own questions, please note that [such has *long* been encouraged on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to), and [we have now made it even easier to do!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz)

Indeed, you are encouraged to spend some time doing *basic* research before asking a question. Right or wrong, the community has a fairly low tolerance for questions that you could have answered yourself after spending a few minutes on a search engine. But there are plenty of things that are hard to find the answer to elsewhere online, or the answers you might find are incorrect, misleading, or confusing. These are the kinds of questions that Stack Overflow is intended to help answer. Our goal is to build up an online resource of *great* answers to programming questions, useful both to the person who originally asked them and to all of the future people who search for answers to the same question.

Therefore, if you cannot find a suitable answer to a question after a reasonable period of searching for it yourself, then you should post a question. And even if you *do* find an answer but it was very difficult to find, then you should consider posting a question and answering it yourself—maybe you'll help others!

---

It's also worth considering that perhaps you're not being downvoted for the *substance* of your posts, but rather the *presentation*.

For example, your question here is rather difficult to read because rather than writing with proper sentences, you just string together random phrases and separate them with long segments of `................`. You should try capitalizing the first letter of the first word in each sentence, and spelling out words in full, rather than using txtspk. Paragraphs and line breaks can also significantly enhance the readability of your contributions.

Comments like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133262/posting-a-question-on-stackoverflow/133264#comment369561_133262) are a great example of the problem:

> actually I have asked questions like these only twice and both the time this happened and i had to delete the questions... sorry 4 that....

Try rewriting that to:

> Actually, I have asked questions like these only twice, and both times this happened, I had to delete the questions. Sorry for that.

Notice that I've capitalized the beginning of a sentence, spelled out the word `for` instead of abusing the numeral `4`, and placed a single period (or comma) between thoughts, rather than a long string of them.

Things like this *do* matter, even on a technically-focused site. Please see our [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more tips on how to use the built-in Markdown syntax to format your posts.

Comment: really touching and extremely helpful.....

Comment: You have pointed out exactly what I am being on this site , and I will try to put them in me for a change. Thanks man

Comment: @The, I'd bet tempted to say *especially* on a technically-focused sites. We're all sticklers for detail in one way or another...