# How to refer to a different answer or comment when answering a question

Tags: support, answers

Often when answering a question, I come across a situation where I would like to refer to a user that left a different answer or a comment on the OP's question, so as to give them credit, like I did in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10697911/1158895).

In this particular situation, a user left a comment on the OP's question, but I felt that I could improve it considerably with a code example, so I did, and I mentioned the username of the user that left the comment (it just seems correct to me to do so) If its just a case of leaving a simple comment, I do so, but if a code example will help, I do that in a separate answer.

Did I do this correctly by including @username in my answer? Or is there a certain 'protocol' or better way to do this? I havent found anything related in the faq.

Comment: I've post a suggestion how to generate reference to other answer in share pop up http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280603/extra-share-option-to-refer-to-others-answer-within-the-same-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibly better way would be:

> As [suggested by SirPentor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695098/how-to-transfer-ifelse-code-segment-by-oop/10697911#comment13884384_10695098), if the Updater classes have a common base class (lets call it UpdaterBase), then define the getUserAnswer() method there, most likely as abstract.
>
> ...

Where the link points to the comment. That way we know exactly what you refer to, be it a comment or an answer. If SirPentor adds another comment somewhere in that question, it won't be very easy to guess what was the suggestion you expanded on. And it wouldn't hurt if you posted a reply to SirPentor's comment, notifying them that you expanded their comment in an answer, I guess it'd be the nice thing to do.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you get a link to a comment?

Comment: @Brady The link to the comment is under the comment's timestamp, the `5 hours ago` part.

Comment: ok, got it, thanks. Do you think this may be worth adding to the faq or Wiki?

Comment: @Brady I don't know if it's documented anywhere, do a quick search and if you don't find anything you can post an MSO question about it and, of course, answer it as well. That would be a great use of the brand new [insta-answer thingy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz). Have at least one screenshot with [free hand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/162704) for sweet & instant Meta rep!

Comment: Ive been considering doing this, but wouldnt posting another MSO question related to this be repeating exactly this questioin?

Comment: @Brady Related yes, but not a duplicate if you make it specifically about how to get links to comments. That said, I'm not sure it's not documented anywhere else...

Comment: @brady there are suggestions to make direct  comment links more intuitive, e.g. having permalink icon - see
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193594/improve-the-usability-intuitiveness-of-direct-comment-links/280567#280567