# How to refer to an answer

Tags: support, answers, referrals

I came across two questions, asking for a solution for the same issue (one could say, one duplicates the other) where both questions are lacking an accepted answer. One answer though lead me to the right solution to fix my problem.

Knowing the solution now, I'd like help others by referring to the correct answer from one thread to the other.
But I'm not sure if I should refer in a comment or an answer.

Is there a certain protocol how to go ahead in this case?

Related question: [How to refer to a different answer or comment when answering a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133266/how-to-refer-to-a-different-answer-or-comment-when-answering-a-question)
The OP however is extending the original answer he is referring to with a code example, whereas I just refer to the answer.

I'm not sure if my referral is worth an answer or if it should better be in a comment.

Comment: Close your question as a duplicate to the question that contains the correct answer?

Comment: This question may involve a bit of context as best practices can change from site to site. Is there a specific SE site that you are asking about?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I'm talking about StackOverflow

Comment: @Luuklag Those are both not my questions, but I flaged it now as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Below every answer you find a *share* link. This link is on the bottom left, to the left of *edit* and *flag* links, which are all on the left of  *edited ...* and *answered ...* links.

The *share* link will bring one directly to the answer. Post it in a comment or in an answer, depending on the specific site policies (comments are intended to be temporary on many sites) and the specific context:  whether you want to comment or to answer.

Comment: While I didn't downvote, this is definitely going to change based on site culture. For example, posting a link in the comments solely as a means to answer the question on RPG.se will likely get it deleted.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose why so?

Comment: @VikingoSsaysReinstateMonica Because comments are temporary tools to help improve the post and attempts to answer the question belong in the answers section where they can be voted on, edited, etc.

Comment: @VikingoSsaysReinstateMonica So basically, if my referal answers the questions, I can just put the share link into an answer. If the refered answer is not the final solution, I'll put in a comment.