# Is it okay to ask a question I know the answer to?

Tags: discussion, questions, guidelines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Is it considered bad form to ask a question specifically for the purpose of answering it for a sect of the community? I mean, you can't get rep for it, right? I've done this really neat thing that doesn't have an answer on SO, and I would love to provide the solution on SO for others looking for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Answering your own questions is both [allowed and encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz).

We now even support it in the UI, so you can post your answer right away along with your question. You will get reputation for both the question and the answer... which can be good or bad, depending on whether the community finds your post valuable. That way there's less chance of someone abusing this mechanism for reputation gain.

Comment: Its for a small sect of the community, but I wanted to make sure. I was more concerned about the intention and abuse. :) I really am enjoying this community quite a bit.