# Are there statistics as to how the instant self-answer is being used?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, instant-self-answer

A while ago [the instant self-answer option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz) was implemented, with the rationale that it would make the "blog" part of the mission statement diagram more...existant. Is there any data about how this change has altered self-answer behaviour? Or is three months still a bit too early to know what it's done?

Comment: I suppose [my first instant self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711730/whats-the-difference-in-the-not-selector-between-jquery-and-css) was pretty well-received.

Comment: I haven't looked at the data explorer in a while (and it could very well be that the current dump precedes this change), but is a post marked in some way that it was self-answered? Or do we rely on matching userid + timestamp?

Comment: Purely anecdotal: my experience is that on smaller sites [this is much better received](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-configure-the-raspberry-pi-to-boot-with-an-nfs-root/629#629) than on [larger sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584599/pass-an-array-to-a-wrapped-function-as-pointersize-or-range/11584600#11584600). (These were both a bit of an experiment for me, my only real conclusion is that it's hard to show research in question you self-answered)