# If I find useful information that I couldn't find on SO, should I create and then answer a question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

If I find an answer on some website to a question that does not already exist on SO

Should I create a question and answer it with the information I've found to 'add to the SO knowlege base' for future visitors?

I tend to search SO first, before google, because chances are I'll find more helpful information here. So shouldn't I add information that isn't here?

Comment: It depends how "useful" your "information" is. If it's something that fits in with the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) then go for it; otherwise please, _please_ don't.

Comment: So long as you're not copying/pasting/plagiarizing too...

Comment: Good point, but what if it's something that paraphrasing would be futile on...not exactly code, but it is perfectly written already

Comment: Keep the policies of the "origin website" in mind. If they say no copying, then don't. If they're CC-BY-SA like us, and you do decide to post to SO, remember to attribute.

Comment: Everyone brings up really good points....I'll throw myself under the bus here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378955/how-can-i-create-a-shortcut-to-dual-boot-between-chromeos-and-ubuntu-easily seems like it's easily found in google, but with newer versions of chromebooks (i think that ) they replaced qemacs with vim editor. So all sites were useless to me..until I found the one I linked to. Is this something I should have shared?

Keep in mind the consensus on SO has been "no,bad"

Comment: @iight, I've just read your question; I _think_ it might have something to do with emacs... I'm really not sure (I use emacs), which is probably why it got downvoted and closed.

Comment: idk....It seems like a useful question related to programming that will help people in the future that search on SO. But -- the people have spoken! :)

Comment: lol and since it got closed...im sure as hell accepting my answer :P hahah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the reason why the "answer your own question" feature has been added in the first place.

You can find this checkbox at the bottom of the "Ask a question" page:

[image: Answer your Question]

Comment: I agree, but - to play devil's advocate, If someone else can simply google really hard and find it...should it be my responsibility to add this content to SO? (as a good-semaritan and to help SO have [even] more content)

Comment: I see...I must have missed that, and as a result got bombarded with downvotes and close votes lol

Comment: Convenience link to [the announcement of that feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz)

Comment: @iight I did not mean the answers to trivial questions that show up at the top of the first google query that you try, I mean answers that took you a while to figure out even with the help of a search engine and one or more external web sites. SO has deservedly gained high visibility in the search engines, so sharing something that you found on other sites is helpful both for the original site and for SO. It goes without saying that the attribution to the original site is a mandatory thing.