# What is the policy on use of Community Wiki? (2013)

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Today I came across a question that I felt it was better suited as a community wiki. Both the question and its accepted answer consisted of a single line, and both had almost 300 upvotes. On top of that, the question was mainly asking for "good practice". It had all the signs of a community wiki to me.

However, when I flagged it as such, the flag got denied on the grounds that "We stopped doing that ages ago".

I was unable to find a recent explanation of what the current policy on making things community wiki is, so I decided just to ask: What is the current policy on making things community wikis?

Is it that posts should never be converted to CW by a moderator, or are there still some cases in which it makes sense to convert a question? (and, by extension, flag it for that purpose)

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Comment: *"Both the question and its accepted answer consisted of a single line, and both had almost 300 upvotes."* - But why does that warrant community wiki? If they're only one line then I can't imagine there was very much community involvement in editing them.

Comment: @Bart thanks. That's an interesting reed. It doesn't completely answer my question (as I'm more interesting in SO's policy and the post seems to be more about "how to (not) use community wiki on your (smaller) SE site"), but it does go a long way.

Comment: @animuson Perhaps it was more based on how I've seen CW used on the part rather than a good reason. I would have voted to close the question if it had been new, but apparently a lot of people do wonder about it, and enough people find the answer useful enough. If I'm not mistaken, that's what CW was often used for in the past.

Comment: Even if we still did CW for questions, why would your particular metrics (single-line answer, 300 upvotes) qualify it for CW status?

Comment: @RobertHarvey This comment (by someone else) why I would CW that question: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/#comment-60636 Interestingly, the only replies to that comment say the question should be closed - which I would be hesitant to do because so many people are interested in it apparently (and a new standard on the horizon is going to change the "correct" answer as well). Note, though, that I'm not trying to appeal the mod's decision, I just included the story how I got to wondering what the current policy is.

Comment: I'd like to contest the possible duplicate question. What I'm looking for is something like "The current policy is not to mark any questions CW and only answers that are truly came to be through team work" (and maybe a line on whether that question sounds like something that should be allowed to live as is, or maybe that it should be closed instead, but that's not essential. (But then the actual policy rather than me making something up.) The duplicate's answer shows it's a quite different question.

Comment: @Jasper From the [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156277/when-did-community-wiki-die/156280#156280) on the proposed duplicate: “Community wiki is for that rare gem of a post that needs true community collaboration.” You do have to follow the link to the blog post for the details, but that does give you the policy you're seeking.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the actual question?

Comment: @Jack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130396/are-there-constants-in-javascript

Comment: Definitely don't think that question should be community wiki. Why should it need to be collaboratively edited any more than any other question?

Comment: Jasper, I just want to try and clarify that this kind of confusion surrounding CW was common, and it is the main reason that we sort of slowly abandoned it. It never really was clear when to use it, so we decided to mostly stop.  Since anyone can suggest an edit to any post now, collaborative editing is built in to the system a bit more thoroughly, so we hardly use CW at all any more.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Thanks, that explanation really helps.