# How do I post tips on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I understand Stack Exchange follows the Q&A format. But how do I share great ideas that I stumble upon and think it maybe useful to others as well?

Comment: In response to a particular question/answer, or just in general?

Comment: If you have a particular problem and find a solution, you can always post a question and answer it yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: in general, say I find so and so practice to be useful in my daily habits. instead of putting up my own blog, I want to add as a tip in stackexchange, which is more visible to wider community.

Comment: @juergend how does that answer the OP's question exactly? If it's a good Q&A pair, a self-answer would suffice, making CW unnecessary. And if that is not the case, it shouldn't be posted to begin with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Formulate it as a question and an answer. [Self-answering questions is allowed and encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz).

There is a big "but" here though: Both the question and answer have to be good. That is, you can't get away with a lousy question just because you add an in-depth answer. Nor will a poor answer suffice if your question is great. All the usual rules for both questions and answers will still apply. In fact, the community (whether fair or not) tends to take a more firm stance on self-answered questions.

If you feel that you can't formulate your "tips" in such a way that it can stand up to scrutiny, Stack Exchange will not be the platform for it. In such a case you're indeed better off posting it on your blog or site.

Comment: The important idea here is that the question and answer are evaluated separately; they are not taken "together".  The question should be, and generally is, evaluated as if it were posted with no answers, and the answer is evaluated as if posted to some other person's question.  It's worth noting that writing a good self answered question is *hard*.  They are often not received well, but that's because they're infrequently written well more so than that the community has higher standards for them.

Comment: Exactly @Servy. It wouldn't be the first time that a question gets evaluated poorly for "showing no research effort", when the OP actually put all of that into the answer.

Comment: And that's not "wrong" of them to do so.  It's not okay to write a crap question just to create a placeholder for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to rewrite your tip as a question & answer. From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer):

> If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.