# How do I refer users?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange

If you invite a friend, be sure to use the special referral link in the Share It popup. If the user commits to the site after using your link, we'll record you as the referrer.

Comment: Are talking about Area 51? you didn't specify it.

Comment: What, where who how? What is this supposed to be? Are you trying to self-answer a question? [This is not the way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz).

Answer (score 2):

There is no "referral" feature on Stack Exchange sites. They are not social networks, they're Q&A sites. We don't give you any particular reward for referring people, and the person whom you refer gets their reward in the form of expert answers to questions they have.

The "share" link to which you refer is a way to share links to questions and answers. That pop-up gives you a link to the post, with a unique identifier at the end that matches your user ID. The system uses that to track how many people you have referred to that particular post. For questions in particular, there are three [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) awarded for this:

- [image: Announcer] for sharing a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses
- ![[Booster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZww0.png) for sharing a link to a question that was visited by 300 unique IP addresses
- [image: Publicist] for sharing a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses

More information is available on [the blog post that announces these badges](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/).

Answer (score 2):

Since the text "If you invite a friend, be sure to use the special referral link in the Share It popup" appears in the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq), I think it's safe to assume that's what you're talking about.

If you go to a site proposal and click on the Share It link, a dialog pops open with a URL you can share.

[image: Share It]

When people you share that URL with commit to the proposal, you'll be recorded as the referrer.

Comment: Hey! you copied [my screenshot and freehand circle](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5QThJ.png).