# Migrate question from chat to Stack Overflow / Programmers?

Tags: discussion, chat, instant-self-answer

I recently searched for an answer to a programming question with Google. After the search did not turn up anything, I went to Stack Overflow chat and asked there, because it was more a question about which solution to a problem I had was best (that means I had a solution already, but wasn't sure if it was best).

After some discussion some alternate solutions came up that I liked better. I had the idea that it might be a good question / answer pair since that way it would be documented for future searching.

So, would it be OK to create a question / answer pair on SO just for reference? Or is it better to just forget about it? What is the SO policy? Does that belong more on Programmers?

Comment: see also: [What is this “answer your own question” jazz?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, create a question (and answer) from the chat discussion.

Absolutely no reason not to - it has the added benefit of not having to trawl through chat and see the whole discussion - just a question and an answer.

It wouldn't hurt to link to the chat transcript, so people can see where it all came from though.

Of course, the question should be on-topic for the site and both question and answer conform to the established quality standards.