# Best practices for moderating self-answered post that actually were not a question

Tags: discussion, moderation, instant-self-answer

Here's a [self-answered question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12559/russian-quality-adjective-ladder). I'm aware that while highly non-typical, self-answered questions are nevertheless acceptable. But in this particular case it looks like the answer was **provided immediately** after the question've been asked.

What are best practices for moderating such self-answered questions that the author obviously knew the answer and pursued some different goals (whatever they are)?

I want to emphasize again that the question is not about self-answered questions, but rather one with about immediately provided answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They're encouraged; don't look down upon them, question them, or discourage them. If the question is in question format, it works. It's a way to share knowledge in the Q&A format.

See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer):

> If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.
>
> To encourage people to do this, there is a checkbox at the bottom of the page every time you ask a question. If you have more than 15 reputation and already know the answer, click the checkbox that says "Answer your own question" at the bottom of the Ask Question page. Type in your answer, then submit both question and answer together.

Comment: oh, ok, good to know, haven't even noticed "Answer your own question" checkbox.

Answer (score 13):

No different than any other self-answered question, which is no different than any other question.

When asking a question, there's even a checkbox beneath the textarea to self-answer, so that the question and answer will be posted simultaneously. So not only is it okay to answer at the same time you ask the question, it's actively encouraged.

[image: "Answer your own question" checkbox]

If you follow the link to [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

> So …
>
> - if you have a question that you already know the answer to
> - if you'd like to document it in public so others (including yourself)
>   can find it later
> - it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant Stack
>   Exchange site.

Whether or not the answer is posted at the same time, shortly after, of after significant further research makes no nevermind.

Comment: Also relevant: [What is this "answer your own question" jazz?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132886)