# Are you allowed to post something non-question related?

Tags: support

I've been wondering if you are allowed to post something non-question related on Stack Exchange.

Like let’s say for example I want to share a cool new feature from an Android update. How would I go about posting it, or are you simply not allowed to post anything that is not a question?

Comment: If you can style it as a question and answer pair. So long as it isn't overly contrived and can be seen as an actual thing someone would reasonably ask.

Comment: So basically asking a question and then answering my own question?

Comment: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz

Comment: Yes, that's allowed. That's why we have an "answer your own question" checkbox in the ask a question page.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking (maybe be even a dupe)

Answer (score 6):

No, you're not allowed to post something that's not a question.