# Instant self-answers are ordered inconsistently

Tags: bug, sorting, api, self-answer, instant-self-answer

When the ["Answer your own question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132886/828089) checkbox is used to provide an instant self-answer, the self-answer has the same creation timestamp as the question, and its ID number is 1 more than the question. When getting lists of posts through the Stack Exchange API, which has various methods to obtain lists of posts that contain both questions and answers, and sorting by the `creation` date, the ordering is inconsistent. Sometimes the question comes before the answer, sometimes the answer comes before the question. The ordering appears to depend on some internal database state.

For instance, [this listing of my posts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-on-users#order=desc&sort=creation&ids=14004262&filter=!3xCtmhSujYzWes3*M&site=stackoverflow&run=true) sometimes returns [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69518903/14004262) first, and sometimes returns [the answer first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69518904/14004262). If you make a bunch of queries in a short period of time, it seems that due to caching the ordering will stay the same, but my daily cron job that hits that endpoint notices the changes.

This also happens in the few places of the website where questions and answers are displayed together. By following a question and an instant self-answer to it, you can see the inconsistent ordering on your Following tab when sorting by Newest:

[image: Bug: self-answer is oldest, question is newer than answer? Normal: question is oldest, answer is newer]

Instead of this current behaviour, the question should always be before the answer. The current ordering implies that answers can be created before their question is. It also breaks the property that when sorting by creation date the IDs are increasing. Changes to the API output that occur when the underlying data doesn't change has caused (minor) problems with my (admittedly fairly fragile) API client.