# knowledge base to stack overflow

Tags: feature-request

Hey everybody

Why not adding a knowledge base to stack overflow (besides questions).
Lets say I figured out something really cool and interesting and I want to share it, so if people will search for something similar they will be able to find it quite easily.

So if I had a knowledge base i could add it there, and people could comment and ask questions about it.

What do you think ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely outside the scope of a Q&A site.

Under certain circumstances however, your knowledge may be suitable as a self-answered question. See this question for details: [Posting and answering questions you have already found the answer to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/moving-a-personal-technical-blog-to-stack-overflow-server-fault)

Answer (score 1):

That is what the tag wiki's are for, albeit that they aren't that obvious but they are there, just hover over the tag and hit 'info' :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure tag wikis aren't for that at all. See the [blog post about them](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-tag-info-pages/)