# Sharing solved problems on SO

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, blog, self-answer, posting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving a personal technical blog to Stack Overflow/Server Fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/moving-a-personal-technical-blog-to-stack-overflow-server-fault)

I don't actually have a blog, not even a tech blog. Also I get an impression that if I had one it would be really hard for it to catch any publicity. On the other hand SO and other similar websites offer great search capabilities, are very popular. I sometimes feel tempted to post a question to which I already know an answer (usually after a day long struggle). Just like I would normally want to share my pain of tracking down some particularly hard bug with other programmers on the web. What's the view of the community on this practice - posting questions along with answers in one of the SO Q&A's?

Comment: and that post has a very straightforward answer by jeff himself

Comment: Yea, this is a duplicate indeed. Thanks.

Comment: hmmm but seems there are mixed views in other posts. I myself have thought of doing this once, but I didn't dare to because I knew there would be mixed opinions about it and I'm a wuss. Possibly post a solved problem as CW would be taken ok since no one could blame you for rep fishing or something.