# Monitor questions for yet non-existing tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I'm the author of an open source project which I would like to support over SO. There are no questions about my project yet, but I would like to be informed if one appears. Is that somehow possible? Can I create the tag and monitor it?

I tried posting some silly question, but it was very soon downvoted and removed. What should I do?

Comment: When you say support do you mean using SO as your bug tracker?

Comment: Not really, I would use SO to explain how to do something to users who get stuck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I tried posting some **silly** question, but it was very soon downvoted
>   and removed.

That's the problem.

Instead, post a *real* question, the way a user would ask it, and then provide a good answer. Answering your own questions is [allowed and encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to), as long as you do both parts well.

If you already have a support forum or mailing list, perhaps you can find a question there to clean up and use here.