# Should I create a Question (+ my own Answer) for difficult problems I have solved

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Posting and answering questions you have already found the answer to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to)

When I have struggled for a long time to solve a problem and then finally find a solution I ask my self if I should add a question for this problem and then also answer the question.

The idea of course is that this would help other who had the same problem.

Comment: Definitely yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is [encouraged behaviour](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).