# Do people actually answer their own questions?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I've never seen people use StackExchange like this.

A few questions:

- First, does anyone use it like this?
- Second, what was the original intention behind this option? What was the vision?

Thanks.

Comment: Not a full answer, but to address your "what was the original intention" question: "one of the design goals for the site: to be a frictionless technical mini-blog" -Jeff Atwood, co-founder ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to/2729#2729) as well as additional context)

Comment: You can look at [this question posted on WorldBuilding.SE today](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/119337/28789) for an example of a self-answered question to share knowledge and at the same time possibly get answers from other people in case you forgot something. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Also, list of high quality self-answers: http://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/856143/well-received-self-answer

Comment: I am pretty sure this [sede query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/131059/advanced-search-for-answers-posted-to-your-questions) can be easily adapted to find them. And of course yes, people do that, and it's even encouraged to do so.

Comment: There's a help page on it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer. I've done it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031066/implementing-an-asynchronous-iterator. It's even set up to let you write the Q & A simultaneously, if you think it's worth sharing what you've found out.

Comment: I do when I have something worth posting but I don't do it everyday or anything, you would have to dig through my Ask Ubuntu profile to see them, if you wanted proof but with hundreds of answers in their, I could not be bothered ;)

Comment: I've done it several times, especially in the [irrlicht] tag on Stack Overflow since Irrlicht isn't very popular so it's otherwise hard to find good questions and answers about it.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for all the comments. It was exactly what I was looking for. As a side note, anybody know why I got so many downvotes? Is this not the sort of question you’re supposed to be asking on Meta?

Comment: I'd guess the downvotes are because even the simplest query would have given you the answer, so it looks like you have just not bothered trying any research before asking.

Comment: @RoryAlsop really? I'm not trying to be aggressive, but how would I do this query? I mean, I did a google search, didn't find any examples, so I asked here.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize some of the comments:

**TL;DR: Yes**

The [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) encourages it, people actually do it, and the community supports the practice by up-voting good questions and good self-answers.

---

From a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313201/do-people-actually-answer-their-own-questions#comment1026113_313201) by [SOLO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/389178/solo):

> ... one of the design goals for the site: to be a frictionless technical mini-blog where you get reputation for your hard work. ~ Jeff Atwood, co-founder *[(source as well as additional context)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to/2729#2729)*

---

Here is a query that shows all the non-CM self-answers on the main META site *(just under a thousand at the time of this writing)*:

https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/893297/well-received-self-answer

To run the query, just open the link to the Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE), and click the "Run Query" button (the query should be run automatically the first time you open the link).